# Manually install the maven plugin for offline mode operation

Tags: maven-3

How to manually install the maven plugin since I have enabled offline mode in settings.xml?

For example I downloaded maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.jar. But I dont know where to place it and how to install it.

Tried http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html but I am not able to install. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the similar question.
Hope this may help you out for installing plugins for maven offlnely.
[Maven: How to install a plugin in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312132/maven-how-to-install-a-plugin-in-offline-mode)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to go online once and run

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

The [go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal of the dependency plugin will "resolve all project dependencies, including plugins and reports and their dependencies."