# How to install JDBC driver using Maven with out Internet connection

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have server which do not have internet connection, i want ti install jdbc driver jar ojdbc7.jar using Maven. I have copied the ojdbc7.jar to .m2 folder manually. And i am trying to install it using below command.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\users\vk\.m2\repository\ojdbc7.jar
    -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

The above command works fine if internet connection is there, i am facing problem and maven build failed due to lack of internet connection. Can anyone tell me how i can install it without internet connection.

Thanks,
Sudheer

Comment: *c:\users\vk\.m2\repository\ojdbc7.jar* - does not look like a valid location

Comment: The purpose of `mvn install` is to copy the local file to your local mvn repository, you should not need to copy it *manually*  - also please post the `error` message

Comment: Are you sure your call to `mvn install` is failing due to an internet connection problem?  I ran it yesterday myself, and it worked.

Comment: If you want to do it manually see https://dzone.com/articles/manually-installing-a-maven-artifact-in-your-local

Comment: Yes its worked fine when i do the same process in other server having internet connection. See the below error

Comment: .[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of
goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file failed: Plug
in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies

Comment: could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugin
s:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> or
g.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.
6 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.4.1: Failed to read artifact descrip
tor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifact
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:pom:1.4.1 from/to central

Comment: (https://repo.maven.a
pache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/1
51.101.68.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException

Comment: *Failed to collect dependencies* install these dependencies first

Comment: What dependencies? how to figure out those dependencies, i am not able to find those dependencies in this error log as well.

Answer (score 0):

The command you used is correct. But the jar you installed might depend on other packages, but these packages are not installed in your .m2 yet. So maven download dependencies for you, so it needs network connection.

If you are trying to install a jar offline because of your machine can't reach network. You need to install all of the dependencies manually with your command. Which might be nightmare for you. I suggest you install your ojdbc7.jar in a network reachable machine, and copy the whole .m2 to your target machine.
Further [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313923/3908814)